# Updating UICollectionView after deleting a Realm object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I try to delete an item from a Realm database I am unable to update a UICollection View appropriately.

Lets assume a Realm container `children` of type `List<Child>`:

```
var children = realm.objects(Parent).first!.children
```

When I want to remove this child from the database by:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.delete(children[indexPath.row])
}
```

updating the collectionView by `collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` gives the following error:

```
Got error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
```

The only way I get the collectionView updated is by using `collectionView.reloadData()`, but that is not what I want since the animation of a cell deletion is missing.

However, when I only remove a child from this container at `indexPath.row` (without removing it from the database) by:

```
try! realm.write {
    children.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
}
```

updating the collectionView with `collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` works without problems.

What would be the best way to update a UICollectionView after removing an item from the database?

Comment: The Problem is you first delete it from  children.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row). Then how it is possible that object is available at that indexPath.row?

Comment: That is true. But in fact I don't want to use 'removeAtIndex'  at all since I want to delete it from the database. I mentioned it because this was the only way I could get the collectionView update working.

Comment: For reloading the collection view you have to remove object from children list. So that collection view get new list.

Answer (score 4):

The error you're facing appears when you keep accessing an object, which was already deleted. So, you're storing likely somewhere a reference to your object, which is fine per se, but keep accessing it after it was [`invalidated`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift6Object11invalidatedSb).

That could happen e.g. in your custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. I'd recommend to implement a setter on your cell and pull from that method the property values into your view components. You can even use KVO in your cell to update these. (We've [an example based on ReactKit](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-2.2/ReactKit) for that up in our repo.) You can't though keep accessing the properties when the object might be already deleted at a later point in time, e.g. if your cell needs to be drawn or layout when it is faded out.

I'd recommend to subscribe to fine-grained notifications for the list you're using to fill your collection view's cells and only propagate updates in that way to the collection view. In that way you can make sure that your items will be removed with a nice animation as requested and it is automatically taken care of. All put together this could look like seen below. Over at our repo, you'll find a [complete runnable sample](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3745/files).

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    func attach(object: DemoObject) {
        label.text = object.title
    }
}

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

    lazy var realm = try! Realm()
    lazy var results: Results<DemoObject> = {
        self.realm.objects(DemoObject)
    }()


    // MARK: View Lifecycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Observe Notifications
        notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let collectionView = self?.collectionView else { return }
            switch changes {
            case .Initial:
                // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                collectionView.reloadData()
                break
            case .Update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(insertions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) })
                    collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(deletions.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) })
                    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(modifications.map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) })
                }, completion: { _ in })
                break
            case .Error(let error):
                // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                fatalError("\(error)")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        notificationToken?.stop()
    }


    // MARK: Helpers

    func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> DemoObject {
        return results[indexPath.row]
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return results.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(object)
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell
        cell.attach(object)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: The deleted object was indeed called in a UICollectionView cell at "layoutSubviews". I did not expect that this method was even called after deletion, but using a setter instead of a direct reference solved the problem!!! With respect to your suggestion to use the notification I still have an issue implementing it. I receive the error: `...The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) …`

Comment: Since I only delete an item I do not understand why the notification handler apparently inserts an item as well. Could you also give me a hint here?

Comment: Are you performing batch updates at any other place in your code?